# How to pass a selected_tab to a controller action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a main tab 'Category'. This tab has two more tabs as 'question' and 'answer'. I have created `CategoryController`, in which I have defined two actions with the name 'question' and 'answer'. I have a method `category_type` in private which should take category_type based on which tab is selected ('question' or 'answer'). This method will be called in the controller's actions. I have created these tabs in views and have also added the routes. How to pass which tab is selected from view to this method?

I have created a partial for these tabs and rendered it on the main page.

`_tabs.html.haml`

```
#secondary-slider.pills-container
  %span
    = link_to 'Questions', question_category_path, class: @selected_tab[:question]
  %span
    = link_to 'Answers',  answer_category_path, class: @selected_tab[:answer]
```

Controller's action:

```
  def question
    @selected_tab = { category_type => :selected }
  end

  alias :question :answer

  private

  def category_type
    @category_type = :question
  end
```

Instead of passing category_type as `:question` or `:answer` as given above, I want to pass params from view i.e. it if `question` tab is selected, the `@category_type` should be passed with `question` else if `answer` tab is selected, it should be passed in `category_type`.

How can this be achieved? I thought of passing 'params()' but couldn't figure out what should be passed in the parenthesis.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass category type from view through `question_category_path` as below,

```
question_category_path(category: 'question')
```

Similar goes for `answer_category_path`

And access which type is selected, in action as `params[:category]`

Comment: I did this but it gave error as `nil is not a symbol nor a string.`  for `category_type`  when I passed the params[:category] in the `category_type` variable

Comment: Use `params[:category] || 'question'` instead of `params[:category]` for initial purpose. Because initial tab to be selected is `question` and action is called with no category key in params.